# how to ajax GET data on already data that received as ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello guys sorry if my question seems wearied.

here is my problem.

have a simple search bar that returns  list of matched records as ajax  ,i.e personal details .

with save record there is a field named "view more" to show full database info of particular field from database.here I am using GET on my ancher  tag to use id values to get result . to have a clear idea please check my url [website url](http://prologicwebsolutions.in/helpinghand/)   use dehra on search bar to get result (as database has only info ).

so my question is how to use the view more link as ajax request to get result .

Comment: what have you tried? give us some PHP where you want to use the get! and read how to post a question in StackOverflow under help! (left of the search input - top of the page)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) Could you post the code that's relevant to your question?

Comment: So, you're asking how you would achieve a 'view more' button, which allows a user to view more content based on a result item?

Comment: Please see the url link i have given in my question ,so you will have a better idea.

Comment: @StupidDojo I would rather not visit links outside of SO, hence why you should post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make an ajax call and show the details by id. one approach will be this

```
<!--Add a class like 'readmore' -->
<a class="readmore" href="./display.php?data1=1">VIEW</a> 

and add a div with `result` class at
<div class="result"></div> <!-- Full view will be showing here -->
```

now in JS

```
$('.readmore').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     //Store the href
     var linkVal = $(this).attr('href');

     //Make an ajax get request 
     $.get( linkVal, function( data ) {
        // create some container where you will display the full details
        $( ".result" ).html( data ); 
     });

});
```

That's is, hope it helps and point you in right direction